Looking to add or append terms in multiple lines using sed command
On our intranet server, we have a control record with almost a hundred lines, with each line corresponding to a program.  Each line has the usernames afterwards of each user that can access and use these programs.  We sometimes get requests for new users to have access mirroring others in similar positions.
Normally I'd use the grep command to get all the instances of that user, write down each line they appear in, then manually update the file with the new user in each line.  As you can imagine, this is time-consuming if the user being mirrored has access to a lot of programs.
I'd like to use sed to find instance of the user being mirrored (We'll call them User1) and append the line with the new user being set up (Who we'll refer to as User2).  I've seen that sed can substitute terms, but not sure how I'd be able to go about adding a new term into an existing line without having to substitute or re-write the entire line
Example:
ProgramABC: User3 User5 User8 User4

ProgramDEF: User9 User1 User3

I want to add User2 in the same line as User1, preferably after User1, without having to rewrite the entire line in the command
I was able to perform this function with a simple command of:
sed 's/User1/User1 User2/' %fileName%
This searched for any instance of the existing user and replaced their name by adding the mirroring user after theirs and did not affect the rest of the line in question.  Once I confirmed the changes, I ran the command again but with the -i argument

This question would be better with an example of the input file format, an example of what you expected the modified file to look like, etc.

Why sed? A perl or bash script would be easier. A better, even easier way would be to use groups. What is the control file used for? Can you make it check groups?

better use code blocks for text in files and such, see the editing help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

The control file is used as a reference for the internal programs, if it is a program that requires authorization it will check against this file and a password file to verify the user in question has access.  It is set up for individual usernames as there are some users that require interdepartmental access whereas others in the same department/group would not

Just be careful that /User1/ will also hit User11, and with that replacement, you then get User1 User21. You'd need to check the username is surrounded by whitespace (or the line end) on both sides. E.g. something like / User1( |$)/ with sed -E. Or perhaps use something like awk (or Perl) that more naturally splits lines into individual fields. (Though then you have to actually loop over the fields instead of just using the regex-hammer.)

Please don't multi-post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78920040/looking-to-add-or-append-terms-in-multiple-lines-using-sed-command

You say "I was able to perform this function with a simple command of:
sed 's/User1/User1 User2/' %fileName%" which sounds like you have a working solution to the problem you described earlier in your question so - what problem are you now trying to solve? (Do try that command if User17 existed on the ProgramABC input line though - you may be surprised).

In other words: Please don’t include answer(s) as part of a question.  Post your answer as an answer.  Or, if you’re saying “This works, but I want something better…”, explain what you don’t like about the answer you have.

sed '/User1/s/$/ User2/' file

Would append  User2 to lines that contain User1 but note that these lines also contain User1:
ControlUser1.5: alice joe
foo: User12
bar: OtherUser1

So it should probably be like:
sed -E '/^.*:.* User1( |$)/s/$/ User2/'

Or if your sed doesn't support -E¹:
sed '/^.*:.* User1\( .*\)\{0,1\}$/s/$/ User2/'

So as to search for User1 only after a : and provided it's preceded by a space and followed by either a space or the end of the line.
To check that User2 is not already in there:
sed -E '/^.*:.* User1( |$)/!b
        /^.*:.* User2( |$)/b
        s/$/ User2/'

Or you could use perl as:
perl -i.orig -lpse '
  if (my ($program, $users) = /^(.*): (.*)/) {
    my %users;
    $users{$_}++ for split " ", $users;
    if ($users{$search_user} && ! $users{$new_user}) {
      print STDERR "Adding $new_user to $program";
      $_ .= " $new_user";
    }
  }' -- -search_user=User1 -new_user=User2 file


¹ though if it supports the non-standard -i option (which a few sed implementations have copied in incompatible fashion from perl), it will likely support -E (or possibly -r if it's an old version of the GNU implementation of sed).
